# Bigquery omni with data on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

Reading some documentations around bigquery omni and i found the [following](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/omni-introduction#location) on the location for aws: aws-us-east-1

Does this mean that the bigquery omni data plane is running in us-east-1 so that data processing will happen in that region? Or does that mean that buckets must be created in us-east-1 ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @zebra, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#data-locations), the location of the Cloud Storage bucket must be the same as the BigQuery dataset location.  The BigQuery dataset must be colocated with the location of the data when you are using external data sources such as AWS. As given in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/omni-introduction#location) , the BigQuery queries can be queried in the same location as of the dataset. So the query will process in us-east-1 only and you need to create the Cloud Storage in the same region as BigQuery dataset if you want to query data in Cloud Storage through a BigQuery external table as data should be colocated i.e. us-east-1.